# ASP.NET MVC 4 update div adtwer Aajax.Beginform

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi, I have a View page:

```
    @using System.Collections.Specialized

    @model USCSAR.ViewModel.ViewAddHardware

    <div class="adminFormsContainer80">

    <center>
        <h5>
            @Resources.Localization.Equipment: @Model.Equipment.Manufacturer @Model.Equipment.Model
        </h5>
        <h6>
            SN: @Model.Equipment.SerialNumber
        </h6>
        <h6>
            @Resources.Localization.InventoryNumber: @Model.Equipment.InventoryNumber
        </h6>
    </center>

    <hr />

    @if (Model != null)
    { 
        using (Ajax.BeginForm("SaveHardware", "Equipment", new AjaxOptions
                                                           {
                                                               HttpMethod = "Post",
                                                               UpdateTargetId = "grid",
                                                               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                                               OnSuccess = "SetDefaultControlValue"
                                                           }))
        {
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Hardware type: ")
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.HardwareID, Model.HardwareType)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Name: ")
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
                    </td>                 
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("SN: ")
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SerialNumber)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Inventory number: ")
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InventoryNumber)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.Label("Installed: ")
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IsInstaled)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>

            <div id="error">
                <center>
                    <p id="errorMassage" class="loginErrorMessage">
                        @Model.Error
                    </p>
                </center>
            </div>

            <center>
                <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="@Resources.Localization.AddNew" />
            </center>
        }
    }

</div>

<div id="grid" class="adminFormsContainer80">
    @{ Html.RenderAction("_AddedHardwareGrid"); }
</div>

@section scripts
{ 
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"></script>

    <script src="~/CustomScripts/SetDefaultControlValue.js"></script>


    <script>

        $(function ()
        {
            SetDefaultControlValue();
        });

    </script>
}
```

The Controllers:

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, SuperAdmin")]
        public ActionResult AddHardware(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                Common.SessionHelper.EquimpentID = id;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }

            return View(new ViewModel.ViewAddHardware());
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, SuperAdmin")]
        public ActionResult SaveHardware(ViewModel.ViewAddHardware item)
        {
            try
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    int equipmentID = item.Equipment.EquipmentID;

                    int hardwareID = item.HardwareID;

                    ViewModel.ViewAddHardware hardware = manager.GetHardwareForEquipmentByEIDandHID(equipmentID, hardwareID);

                    if (hardware == null)
                    {
                        manager.SaveHardwareForEquipment(item);
                    }
                    else if (hardware != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Error))
                    {
                        item.Error = Resources.Localization.HardwareExist;
                        return View("AddHardware", item);
                    }
                    else if (hardware != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Error))
                    {
                        manager.SaveHardwareForEquipment(item);
                    }

                    List<ViewModel.ViewAddHardwareGrid> model = manager.GetHardwareForEquipmentByEquipmentID(equipmentID);

                    return PartialView("_AddedHardwareGrid", model);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return View("Error");
            }

            return View("AddHardware", item);
        }
```

I woluld like to achive, that when this code executes in Controller

```
else if (hardware != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Error))
                    {
                        item.Error = Resources.Localization.HardwareExist;
                        return View("AddHardware", item);
                    }
```

in the View the DIV below update the Models error message:

```
<div id="error">
                <center>
                    <p id="errorMassage" class="loginErrorMessage">
                        @Model.Error
                    </p>
                </center>
            </div>
```

thnx

Comment: what is you question ? Please edit your title

Comment: Sorry, the question is how to update the ,,error,, div's content after the ajax post response.

Answer (score 0):

It is obvious that you have to do it using client-side JavaScript code, but not using ASP.Net MVC constructions. Assuming that you are calling your controller with jQuery, you may try the following code:

`$( "#errorMessage" ).html( errorMessage );`

where `errorMessage` is a string containing error message received from the server.

Comment: As I can see, the Error property gets back, its in the model, but it not shows, and the

$( "#errorMessage" ).html( errorMessage ); wont work for me.I need to show the message and I need that message to travel back again to controler, but it not.